# Assign unique slugs to set of people. Slugs are as short as possible. (New elements only added to ensure uniqueness.)

Tags: python

I have a Python function that will terminate when some condition is fulfilled.
That could happen after the first (easy) step. But more steps (of increasing complexity) may follow.

Below is the simplified example function `find_slugs`.
For each person in `database` it finds a slug, which is unique and as short as possible.

To avoid code repetition it was necessary to create the subfunction `maybe_finish`.
It checks if the slugs are already unique, and returns the result if they are.
Otherwise it prepares the next step by creating `blocks_to_refine`, and returns `None`.

Between the steps are conditional returns, contracted to one line:

```py
if maybe_result := maybe_finish(): return maybe_result
```

In three lines it would look like this:

```py
maybe_result = maybe_finish()
if maybe_result is not None:
    return maybe_result
```

Repeating this line does not seem like an elegant solution to me.
(It is essentially repeating three lines of code again and again.)

I would be interested in different approaches to this example problem.

For the given list of people the result is `{0: 'JohnSpam85a', 1: 'JohnSpam85b', 2: 'JohnEggs91', 3: 'JohnEggs92', 4: 'EmmaFish95a', 5: 'EmmaFish95b', 6: 'MaryBeer', 7: 'MaryWine', 8: 'Owen', 9: 'Ruth'}`. For the first three it is `{0: 'JohnSpam85a', 1: 'JohnSpam85b', 2: 'JohnEggs'}`. For the last three `{7: 'Mary', 8: 'Owen', 9: 'Ruth'}`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict


database = {
    0: {'name1': 'John', 'name2': 'Spam', 'born': '1985'},  # JohnSpam85a
    1: {'name1': 'John', 'name2': 'Spam', 'born': '1985'},  # JohnSpam85b
    2: {'name1': 'John', 'name2': 'Eggs', 'born': '1991'},  # JohnEggs91
    3: {'name1': 'John', 'name2': 'Eggs', 'born': '1992'},  # JohnEggs92
    4: {'name1': 'Emma', 'name2': 'Fish', 'born': '1995'},  # EmmaFish95a
    5: {'name1': 'Emma', 'name2': 'Fish', 'born': '1995'},  # EmmaFish95b
    6: {'name1': 'Mary', 'name2': 'Beer', 'born': '2000'},  # MaryBeer
    7: {'name1': 'Mary', 'name2': 'Wine', 'born': '2000'},  # MaryWine
    8: {'name1': 'Owen', 'name2': 'Wine', 'born': '2000'},  # Owen
    9: {'name1': 'Ruth', 'name2': 'Milk', 'born': '2000'}   # Ruth
}

alphabetical_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']


def find_slugs():

    def maybe_finish():
        # A block is a list of numbers with (currently) the same slug.
        slug_to_block = defaultdict(list)
        for number, slug in number_to_slug.items():
            slug_to_block[slug].append(number)
        if len(slug_to_block) == len(database):
            return number_to_slug
        nonlocal blocks_to_refine
        blocks_to_refine = []
        for block in slug_to_block.values():
            if len(block) > 1:
                blocks_to_refine.append(block)

    ##################################################################

    blocks_to_refine = None  # created and updated in `maybe_finish`

    number_to_slug = dict()  # result

    # step 1: start with first name
    for number, table_row in database.items():
        number_to_slug[number] = table_row['name1']

    if maybe_result := maybe_finish(): return maybe_result

    # step 2: add last name
    for block in blocks_to_refine:
        for number in block:
            number_to_slug[number] += database[number]['name2']

    if maybe_result := maybe_finish(): return maybe_result

    # step 3: add year of birth
    for block in blocks_to_refine:
        for number in block:
            number_to_slug[number] += database[number]['born'][2:4]

    if maybe_result := maybe_finish(): return maybe_result

    # step 4: append letter to year of birth
    for block in blocks_to_refine:
        for i, number in enumerate(block):
            number_to_slug[number] += alphabetical_letters[i]

    return number_to_slug
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I did not change the question. I simply added some code at the end, that can be used to measure the performance of the different approaches.

Comment: That code is now in my own answer.

Comment: To improve consistency of output, is it possible to _always_ form a string from the name fields, birth date and letter? If not, why not?

Comment: Are these strings user-facing? If not, why not form a shortest unique hash prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is my improvement of the code by *301_Moved_Permanently*.
The crucial feature in that answer was the return of a generator by `find_duplicates`.
But (as mentioned by *Matthieu M.*) it is not efficient, to check all slugs for duplicates. Instead, the function should refine the duplicates from the last step. That requires using the generator twice: First in the for-loop to append the slugs, and then in the next call of `find_duplicates`. As generators can only be used once, it is doubled with `itertools.tee`.

```py
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable

def double_generator(gen): return itertools.tee(gen, 2)


def find_duplicates(number_to_slug, dup_gen_to_refine=None):
    slug_to_numbers = defaultdict(list)
    if dup_gen_to_refine is not None:
        for number in flatten(dup_gen_to_refine):
            slug = number_to_slug[number]
            slug_to_numbers[slug].append(number)
    else:
        for number, slug in number_to_slug.items():
            slug_to_numbers[slug].append(number)
    for block in slug_to_numbers.values():
        if len(block) > 1:
            yield block


def find_slugs(database):
    number_to_slug = {}  # result

    # step 1: start with first name
    for number, table_row in database.items():
        number_to_slug[number] = table_row['name1']

    # step 2: add last name
    dup_gen = find_duplicates(number_to_slug)
    dup_gen_to_append, dup_gen_to_refine = double_generator(dup_gen)
    for number in flatten(dup_gen_to_append):
        number_to_slug[number] += database[number]['name2']

    # step 3: add year of birth
    dup_gen = find_duplicates(number_to_slug, dup_gen_to_refine)
    dup_gen_to_append, dup_gen_to_refine = double_generator(dup_gen)
    for number in flatten(dup_gen_to_append):
        number_to_slug[number] += database[number]['born'][2:4]

    # step 4: append letter to year of birth
    dup_gen = find_duplicates(number_to_slug, dup_gen_to_refine)
    dup_gen_to_append, dup_gen_to_refine = double_generator(dup_gen)
    for block in dup_gen_to_append:
        for letter, number in zip(alphabet, block):
            number_to_slug[number] += letter

    return number_to_slug
```

This does not look very elegant, as there is some code duplication in each step.
I tried looping through a list of functions, as suggested by *FMc*, but for some reason that comes with some cost in performance. (That is `fun4`. It is not shown here, but [on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/rq72726Z).)

I used the following code to generate a database with 112750 rows:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase as alphabet

db_list = []

for a, b in product(range(5), range(5)):
    row = {'name1': alphabet[a], 'name2': alphabet[b], 'born': '2000'}
    for _ in range(10):
        db_list.append(row)

for a, b, c in product(range(5, 20), range(5, 20), range(100)):
    row = {'name1': alphabet[a], 'name2': alphabet[b], 'born': str(1900 + c)}
    db_list.append(row)

for i, j in product(range(300), range(300)):
    row = {'name1': str(i) + 'x', 'name2': str(j) + 'y', 'born': '2000'}
    db_list.append(row)

long_database = {}
for i, row in enumerate(db_list):
    long_database[i] = row
```

The following code is to measure the performance of each approach:
(I modified all functions to take `database` as an argument, and to use `ascii_lowercase`.)

```py
from timeit import timeit

number_of_repetitions = 100
for i, fun in enumerate([fun0, fun1, fun2, fun3, fun4, fun5]):
    long_time = timeit(lambda: fun(database), number=number_of_repetitions)
    short_time_str = round(long_time / number_of_repetitions, 3)
    print(f'fun{i} took {short_time_str} seconds')
```

This is the result:

```
fun0 took 0.125 seconds  # my initial code
fun1 took 0.189 seconds  # answer by FMc
fun2 took 0.129 seconds  # answer by 301_Moved_Permanently
fun3 took 0.104 seconds  # this answer
fun4 took 0.136 seconds  # like fun1 and fun3 (on Pastebin)
fun5 took 0.102 seconds  # improvement by 301_Moved_Permanently (on Pastebin)
```

`fun5` uses `with` and a class with `__enter__` and `__exit__`. It can be found [on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/RWcQK7ab).

Comment: With 27 people with identical details, you'll get a duplicate; to have guaranteed absence of duplicate, you need to iterate the last step until there's none.

Comment: Sure, but we should neglect that.

Comment: See also [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) or at least [`time.perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) instead of `time.time`.

Comment: All answer code must be embedded and not linked.

Answer (score 3):

**Clarify the real problem**. Your question focuses on how to deal with the
repeated if-finished checks. But that repetition is just a small part of a
larger repetition across the four slug-creation steps. Steps 2 and 3 are
already identical in form: iterate over `blocks_to_refine` and then over
`block`, appending to the slugs as we go. Step 4 differs from 2 and 3 only
because it uses `enumerate()`. Step 1 seems more different because we are
setting `number_to_slug` values rather than appending to them. But all of those
differences can be ironed away by (a) using `enumerate()` across all steps and
(b) initializing variables differently so that even Step 1 operates by
appending. In other words, we want every step to have the same structure:

```
for block in blocks_to_refine:
    for i, n in enumerate(block):
        number_to_slug[n] += ...
```

**Define a list of slug functions to compute what needs to be appended**. To
execute the four steps, just iterate over those functions. After each step,
check whether you are done and possibly return early. Since we have eliminated
the code repetition, there's no need to resort to awkward inner functions and
reliance on resetting nonlocal variables (whenever you find yourself feeling
the need for the latter, take it as a sign that bigger refactoring might be
needed).

```python
def find_slugs():
    # Returns a dict mapping each DB number to a unique slug.

    # Initialize the return value and the DB numbers that need processing.
    slugs = {n : '' for n in database}
    todo = [list(slugs)]

    # Functions to compute each slug element.
    slug_funcs = [
        lambda _, n: database[n]['name1'],
        lambda _, n: database[n]['name2'],
        lambda _, n: database[n]['born'][2:4],
        lambda i, _: alphabetical_letters[i],
    ]

    # Build the slugs.
    for sf in slug_funcs:
        for block in todo:
            for i, n in enumerate(block):
                slugs[n] += sf(i, n)

        # Dict mapping each slug to its DB numbers.
        slug_to_nums = defaultdict(list)
        for n, slug in slugs.items():
            slug_to_nums[slug].append(n)

        # Return if all slugs unique.
        if len(slug_to_nums) == len(database):
            return slugs

        # DB numbers for slugs needing refinement.
        todo = [
            ns
            for ns in slug_to_nums.values()
            if len(ns) > 1
        ]

    return slugs
```

Comment: Thank you for that great answer. There is just a small problem with your code. To make it visible, I have added two more people with the same name and birth year. With your code they become `EmmaFish95c` and `EmmaFish95d`. But of course, the letters should always start at the beginning of the alphabet. In my code, that is what the blocks are for.

Comment: Do you see a reason for the performance loss that coincides with looping through step functions? As far as I can see, `fun1` (yours) does essentially the same as `fun0` (my initial code), and `fun4` is just a nicer way to write `fun3`. Is there a way to have the improved readability without the loss in performance?

Answer (score 3):

`maybe_finish` building a list of list does not feel great here, also using the `database` variable only for a quick shortcut does not feel necessary either as the complexity is still \$O(2n)\$. Consider `yield`ing your blocks instead and [`flatten`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) them from the call site.

`alphabetical_letters` is not necessary either as [it already exist in the `string` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase). You also don't need to use a list here, strings are indexable too.

Consider passing `database` as a parameter to the `find_slugs` function, this ease reuse and testing. In fact, given your example input, using [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) here seems like a sensible thing to do.

Proposed improvements:

```py
import itertools
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet
from collections import defaultdict


flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable


def find_duplicates(slugs):
    similar_slugs = defaultdict(list)
    for number, slug in slugs.items():
        similar_slugs[slug].append(number)
    for same_slug in similar_slugs.values():
        if len(same_slug) > 1:
            yield same_slug


def build_slugs(database):
    """Convert rows from the database into a unique slug
    as short as possible for each row.

    >>> database = {
    ...     0: {'name1': 'John', 'name2': 'Spam', 'born': '1985'},
    ...     1: {'name1': 'John', 'name2': 'Spam', 'born': '1985'},
    ...     2: {'name1': 'John', 'name2': 'Eggs', 'born': '1991'},
    ...     3: {'name1': 'John', 'name2': 'Eggs', 'born': '1992'},
    ...     4: {'name1': 'Emma', 'name2': 'Fish', 'born': '1995'},
    ...     5: {'name1': 'Emma', 'name2': 'Fish', 'born': '1995'},
    ...     6: {'name1': 'Mary', 'name2': 'Beer', 'born': '2000'},
    ...     7: {'name1': 'Mary', 'name2': 'Wine', 'born': '2000'},
    ...     8: {'name1': 'Owen', 'name2': 'Wine', 'born': '2000'},
    ...     9: {'name1': 'Ruth', 'name2': 'Milk', 'born': '2000'},
    ... }
    >>> build_slugs(database)
    {0: 'JohnSpam85a', 1: 'JohnSpam85b', 2: 'JohnEggs91', 3: 'JohnEggs92', 4: 'EmmaFish95a', 5: 'EmmaFish95b', 6: 'MaryBeer', 7: 'MaryWine', 8: 'Owen', 9: 'Ruth'}
    """
    number_to_slug = {}  # result

    # step 1: start with first name
    for number, table_row in database.items():
        number_to_slug[number] = table_row['name1']

    # step 2: add last name
    for number in flatten(find_duplicates(number_to_slug)):
        number_to_slug[number] += database[number]['name2']

    # step 3: add year of birth
    for number in flatten(find_duplicates(number_to_slug)):
        number_to_slug[number] += database[number]['born'][2:4]

    # step 4: append letter to year of birth
    for block in find_duplicates(number_to_slug):
        for letter, number in zip(alphabet, block):
            number_to_slug[number] += letter

    return number_to_slug


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    print(doctest.testmod())
```

Comment: Lovely concise implementation. I would advise replacing `number` with a better name, `index` would be better for example. And if we have an `index`, we don't need a `map`, only a `list` for `slugs`. The second issue I have is the performance of `find_duplicates`: I'd favor a different function splitting the "solved" slugs from the unsolved ones, so the solved ones don't have to be re-iterated over at every step. Oh... and really the last step needs to keep iterating until there's no duplicate left; if I supply 16 person with identical details until then, the current version fails badly.

Comment: My new answer builds upon this one. I have modified `find_duplicates` to refine the duplicates from the last step, instead of looping through all slugs in each step. (BTW, I tried up to 26 people with identical details, and there is no problem.)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Hum… `number` didn't bother me as it is, in essence, a row number. However, knowing this data come from a database, it may be better to reason about a (primary) `key` here, hence not necessarily an index worthy of changing the datastructure. As for `find_duplicates` I totally agree, went on trying to address this issue (see https://pastebin.com/T74adsaD) but tossed it aside by lack of time. As with [Watchduck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/285213/84718) solution, this one feels clanky and full of boilerplate.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Oh, and your last point, I don't think it has been mentioned in an answer yet ;)

Comment: With "feels clanky and full of boilerplate" you mean the code duplication in each step? Or do you see that also in `fun4` [on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/rq72726Z)?

Comment: @Watchduck Yeah, code duplication is about the boilerplate aspect, which is largely reduced in your pastebin. I could also reduce it a bit by [changing the variable names instead of relying on comments](https://pastebin.com/RWcQK7ab). The clankyness is largely due to the "WAT" factor of using non-obvious side effects during the context manager cleanup.

Comment: I added your new code with the `ExtractUniquesInto` class as `fun5` to the list. The performance is basically like my `fun3`.

Answer (score 2):

## nested def

Sometimes I will diplomatically explain that
nesting defs causes excessive coupling similar to
[global variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable),
and is a technique you should probably avoid.
Plus it impacts
[testability](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).
But here, I will just come right out and say it.

No.
Do not nest `maybe_finish()` as you've done.
Break it out as a separate helper,
and use explicit parameters to communicate with it.
Pass in `number_to_slug`.

As written, it is unclear what its
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
is, and it's hard to reason about its
[contracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).

Possibly it should be a pair of helpers:
one that compares lengths and another that works on blocks to refine.

Do not implicitly return a value when dropping off the
end of the function, since this is not a procedure
that is strictly being evaluated for side effects.
Prefer an explicit `return None`.

---

## appropriate name

The single biggest thing wrong with `def maybe_finish():`
is that it is just a terrible name.
It doesn't help the Gentle Reader to identify
its purpose, and no """docstring""" or `# comment`
linked "uniqueness" to the notion of being finished.
Consider renaming this predicate to `slugs_are_unique`
or `slugs_unique`.

[ EDIT: After my review the question's title was updated to give *exactly* the help I sought from a docstring as I was trying to read the code: "Assign unique slugs to set of people. Slugs are as short as possible. (New elements only added to ensure uniqueness.)" ]

---

## mixed type

```
    blocks_to_refine = None  # created and updated in `maybe_finish`
```

No.
Initialize to `[]` the empty list,
rather than telling
[mypy](https://pypi.org/project/mypy)
it is an `Optional[list]`.
Or perhaps this could be entirely local to `maybe_finish()`?

---

Kudos, the `number_to_slug` return variable is well named.

---

## conventional loop variable

```
    for number, table_row in ...
```

The identifier `number` is accurate, but rather vague.
I was left wondering if it was some summary statistic over the row data.
And then I saw what it was being used for.

Prefer the index variable `i` for simple loops such as this.

---

## iterate over functions

There are four steps.
Consider adding four unit tests which trigger each of the four `return`s.

Define four helpers:

- `set_first_name()`
- `add_last_name()`
- `add_birth_year()`
- `append_letter()`

Now you no longer need four tests for early return,
as writing it once suffices:

```
steps = [set_first_name, add_last_name, add_birth_year, append_letter]
for step in steps:
    step(number_to_slug)
    if maybe_result := maybe_finish(number_to_slug):
        return maybe_result
```